# how to change color in pdf file

Tags: pdf, adobe-acrobat, acrobat-pro-dc

Example of the problem in the PDF file:

[image]

How can I remove the blue color from this PDF file?

Acrobat Reader does not recognize it as background or highlighted text.

The pro version allows me to remove it manually, but it is very clumsy, and I need to remove it from many documents.

Is there a way to remove all objects of this blue color from the PDF documents?

Comment: Does the program need to run under Windows or is Linux also fine? Do you have experience with working on the command line?

Comment: windows, i do not have experience

Comment: Do you just want to replace the blue with white? Or do you want to remove the character as well?

Comment: i want to replace the blue with white

Comment: the solution that i found to this problem was: 1) go to tools --> optimize pdf -->preflight ---> profiles ---> convert to grayscale and then tone value adjustment in mid tones by 10% (several times ) .